# Iptv Player Application?

Tags: android, iptv

I recently bought the strongest iptv playlist iptv4kprovider. So I would like to develop an application to play these multicast-ed streams using my Android media player IPTV.

Could somebody guide me on this?

Thanks a lot,

Ag

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.